# Working of scanf under for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I have a question about working of for loop in C. Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int ar[10],i;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers:");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d",ar[i]);
}
```

When I execute this and give the following input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I have given 12 inputs but the loop was supposed to run for only 10 times (scanf loop). I can give even more inputs and it is happy to take it unless I hit enter key. Is there something about for loop that I'm missing here?

Comment: You can enter as many numbers as you like, but it'll only read 10 of them. Where you might get a problem is the next time you try to call `scanf()`, because those extra numbers will still be there, waiting to be read.

Comment: Should For loop not run for only 10 times @PaulGriffiths?

Comment: Should and does. That's why it'll only read 10 of your 12 numbers. The first iteration of the loop won't end until you hit Enter, though, so by the time your second iteration starts, there are 11 numbers sitting waiting to be read. Your `scanf()` call will read individual numbers separated by whitespace, whether that whitespace is a newline, or just regular spaces. After your first `scanf()` call returns, it'll just have read the first number, and the rest of your line is still waiting in the input buffer for the next `scanf()` call.

Comment: if you want to read 10 numbers you should terminate the line after every input instead of one line... maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following program will help you visualize what's going on:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ar[10], br[2], i;
    printf("Enter 12 numbers: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    for( i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }

    printf("We've read the first 10, let's print them...\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }

    printf("\nNow, let's read the last 2...\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
        scanf("%d", &br[i]);
    }

    printf("We've read the last 2, let's print them...\n");

    for( i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
        printf("%d ", br[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./scanning
Enter 12 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
We've read the first 10, let's print them...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Now, let's read the last 2...
We've read the last 2, let's print them...
11 12 
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

As you'll see, after reading the first ten, the last two numbers are still in the input buffer, and we can read them in a separate loop without actually asking for any more input. In this case, all the inputting is done after the end of the *first* call to `scanf()`. The program can just continue to read whatever's in the input buffer without the user ever having to hit another key.

What happened with your program is that you just returned from `main()` and quit without ever attempting to read those last two numbers you input. This example program shows that they're still in there, available to be read, however.

If you run the example program but you enter *less* than 12 numbers, then at some point the input is going to run out, and `scanf()` is going to stop and wait for you to enter some more before continuing.

Comment: So if we had entered only 11 numbers at first then scanf would ask me to enter values once more. If that is the case then I have understood the logic. Also will the logic be same if the array was of type character used to print ten character on screen. Thank you Paul.

Comment: @imox: Yes, if you entered 11, you'd see up to `Now, let's read the last 2...` and then `scanf()` would stop and wait for you to enter more input on the second iteration of the third `for` loop. The logic is not quite the same with a `char` array, since while `scanf()` will read `int`s separated by whitespace, for instance, when it's reading characters it'll just treat whitespace, including newlines, like any other character. So if you actually entered 10 characters, it would be able to read 11 - the 10 you entered, plus the newline character. If you separated them with spaces, there'd be 20.